# What is the best way to convert or copy an VM image into an lvm?

Tags: lvm, conversion

I have a couple of VMs running on images instead of lvms. I am not concerned about downtime but just about convenience of the process.

Comment: Do you want to keep snapshots or such?  Because otherwise you can use the same tools you would use to copy any other image or its contents (= backup & restore)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a short discussion at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/33858/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-vmware-vmdk-image-file-to-phyaical-hardisk-drive), hope it helps :-)